# Converting an Array to Javaslang Map with counts for each type

Tags: java, java-8, vavr

I am currently looking at Javaslang library and I am trying to convert some of my code to Javaslang.

I currently have this bit of code which is all pure Java

```
Cell[][] maze; //from input
Map<Cell, Long> cellCounts = Stream.of(maze)
            .flatMap(Stream::of)
            .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting()));
```

I was looking at converting this to Javaslang, as I am interested in the library and I just wanted to play around with it.

I am trying to do a similar thing, but convert to a Javaslang map instead of the java.util.Map.

I have tried this so far but then I am getting stuck as I cant see a way of converting it.

```
Array.of(maze)
     .flatMap(Array::of)
```

So I have my list of Cell objects, but I am trying to figure out how to convert this to a javaslang.collection.Map

*EDIT *

I have looked at getting my original java.util.Map to a javaslang.collections.Hashmap by this

```
HashMap<Cell, Long> cellsCount = HashMap.ofEntries(cellCounts
                                                        .entrySet()
                                                        .toArray(new Map.Entry[0]));
```

This still doesnt seem to be in line with Javaslang, but I will keep looking.

Comment: is there any implementation of `javaslang.collection.Map` that would extend `java.util.Map`?

Comment: No, the rewrote javaslang.collection.Map from the ground up. They took a functional approach to designing it and have made all the collections Immutable as well.

Comment: Inmutable collections is not a good idea all the times. It depends on the size of the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of Javaslang.

This simplest way to achieve it with Javaslang is the following:

```
    Map<Cell, Integer> cellCounts = Array.of(maze)
            .flatMap(Array::of)
            .groupBy(c -> c)
            .mapValues(Array::length);
```

Here `Array` and `Map` are imported from `javaslang.collection`.

Please note that you can substitute `Array` with any other `Seq` or `Set` implementation.

Comment: Thanks daniel, I have been following javaslang for a bit so when I saw that it was your user answering I was very pleased.

Comment: Hi Ash, yes - I remember you :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally grouping by has another method that takes a Map implementation you are trying to convert to, but it has to be of a type that actually extends `java.util.Map`:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)
```

From what I see `javaslang.collection.Map` is an interface, not an actual implementation.

Since there are no implementations of a javaslang Map that would extend `java.util.Map`, all you can do is create a custom collector.

Or once already collected to `java.util.Map` - put those into some instance of `javaslang.collection.Map`.

Comment: This answer (the last part) is the correct one - by using methods like `HashMap::ofAll(java.util.Map)` one can easily put all contents of any Java `Map` into a Javaslang one.

Answer (score 3):

While [answer that Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535604/7470253) provided is true in general: *someone* has to make a custom Collector.

However, that doesn't necessarily have to be you: Javaslang guys already taken care of it for you, by providing necessary methods available on concrete implementations of Javaslang maps that will work in simplest cases. For example, on Javaslang `HashMap`:

> [javaslang.collection.HashMap::collector()](http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.4/javaslang/collection/HashMap.html#collector--)
>
> public static <K,V> Collector<Tuple2<K,V>,ArrayList<Tuple2<K,V>>,HashMap<K,V>> collector()
>
> Returns a Collector which may be used in conjunction with Stream.collect(java.util.stream.Collector) to obtain a HashMap.
>
> **Type Parameters**:
>
> K - The key type
>
> V - The value type
>
> **Returns**:
>
> A HashMap Collector.

**Edit:**
However, it doesn't look like that will necessarily work, because judging from the collector's signature it:

1. Expects a stream of `Tuple<K,V>`
2. Collects all elements of that stream into an `ArrayList<Tuple2<K,V>>`
3. After all elements were collected, it "finishes" by adding all contents of that `ArrayList` into a `HashMap`.

This obviously will not work, since you have `Stream<Cell>`, and you want to count them. However, that signature actually gives us a few things: it points out that builtin Javaslang collector does not collect directly into Javaslang Map (at least not in `HashMap`). Knowing this, we can look for method to convert Java Map into Javaslang map, and what we'll find will be:

> [javaslang.collection.HashMap::ofAll(java.util.Map)](http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.4/javaslang/collection/HashMap.html#ofAll-java.util.Map-)
>
> Returns a HashMap, from a source java.util.Map.

We can add this method on top of what you have like this:

```
Stream<Cell> cells // <- you have this

cells.collect(
  collectingAndThen(
    groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()),
    HashMap::ofAll
  )
);
```

All methods without qualifiers you can find in `java.util.stream.Collectors`.

This snippet will collect into normal Java `Map`, and as last step will call Collector's Finisher that will put all values from java Map into Javaslang map.

*Note: I do not have Javaslang installed, and cannot test if above snippet compiles, but it looks like it does what you want.*

Comment: I have been looking at this, but to get it to work, do you have to convert your current stream to `Tuple2`? and have already counted the values?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I messed up a little. From the collector signature it does look like it collects `Tuple2` into an `ArrayList`, and then just adds all those into `HashMap`. This will not work for you, but we can sort of mimic this bevavior by using other builtin methods in a way that will work. I will keep initial version, but will update with my version of code.

Comment: @Ash, would this new variant work for you? Do you need more info about it?

Comment: Seems to be perfect, I didnt realize there was a `collectingAndThen()`